# linux - Bash Terminal not allowing usage of scripts even if terminal is at current directory of script itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So,I had Fedora installed in my computer,since Windows gave me no choice last time.

Then after I installed Fedora,I learned that Fedora was actually Linux - only modified,and thus,I wanted to try out the programming language that it has - BASH.

And my search for tutorials went on,and I found one.And it tole me to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World.
```

Then,I wanted to try it out,so I saved it as testscript.sh and then,opened Terminal,and this happened.

```
[JRGarcia@localhost ~]$ ./testscript.sh
bash: ./testscript.sh : command not found
```

So,I thought to myself: "That just ain't right!"
And then,on went my rampant rage across my room,and everything I have is destroyed right now.

What do I have to do? I saw some videos on tutorials and that method worked fine for them.BTW,I saved the script in the /home/JRGarcia,which is what Terminal uses as a starting directory.

Comment: `chmod +x,+r testscript.sh` ?

Comment: or just `bash testscript.sh` ?

Comment: nope.tried that as well after i posted this question.didnt work as well.

Comment: `ls -lhas` in this dir.

Comment: @Will Vousden: `bash script.sh` starts a new process. `source script.sh` does what you say.

Comment: @chatraed Of course – not thinking straight!

Comment: @rHaLeX_does_programs: what does `type echo` output in your terminal?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov i just tried that and it returned with: a bunch of lines noting the diff. attribs of everything and it showed the attribs of testscript.sh with: -rw-rw-r--

Comment: @rHaLeX_does_programs Is this a joke? If yes, please note that stackoverflow is not funny and hit the road!

Comment: @hek2mgl no it is not.i am very serious.this is a matter i have been positively angry at for a couple of hours now.

Comment: It could be possible that `echo` is aliased in your environment. That's why I ask you to show the output of `type echo`

Comment: Problem solved.Reinstalled Fedora.And tried out answer given by @PSkocik.Somehow.

Comment: @twalberg seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat > testscript.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World.
^D
$ chmod +x testscript.sh
$ ./testscript.sh         #=> Hello world.
```

Works fine.

Comment: The OP doesn't say anything about marking the file as executable with `chmod`, which is a necessary step for it to work.

Comment: Huh.That's weird.When I tried the suggestion given by @PSkocik,it didn't work.But now it did.

Comment: @rHaLeX_does_programs It is a miracle! :D

Comment: Now I'll just have to wait for the time limit to disperse,then I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `x` permission on the script and cannot execute it, it may be because you mounted the current partition with the option `noexec`. [See explanation in manpage of mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

You can verify this by running the `mount` command without any arguments.

Comment: He'd get `-bash: ./testscript.sh: Permission denied` on `stderr` if that were the case, but +1.